# browser close should call logout function in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am working on an application using node.js and angularjs and i am novice in both of them. My major requirement is not to use jquery/ajax call. When i close the browser tab/ refresh, Logout function in a service should call. I already tried using onbeforeunload. But its not working for nodejs. Is there any method to call my logout function written in service when my browser tab closed/refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

Logout functions usually are for the front end for example when a user logs in successfully, you can do localStorage.setItem('loggedin', 'true'); then use this to check if a user is logged in across all components. When they log out then you can just do localStorage.clear(); and that means the user will be logged out. That's how I'd do it. To answer the Nodejs part, for you to call a function in your backend Nodejs service, you have to add a custom remote method then call it from your Angular app.

Comment: Thats obvious. But it doesnt work when i close the browser tab/ refresh. Yes we can Custom remote method. But before that the server should know when the browser tab close. Then only we can call the custom remote method in that. My question is how to notify the server that the browser is closed?

Comment: @Umakarthika well then, you shouldn't have a problem because whatever it is you wanna call when you refresh/load the browser should go in the ngOnInit() of your app.component.ts

Comment: Is that ngOnInit() directive available in angularjs??